# How to draw a bitmap on a tft display?

Tags: arduino-mega, display

I'd like to print a bitmap on my TFT.

I setup my screen with this library: http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=292777.0

It is like the Adafruit_GFX library (only a little bit changed). Everything works.

With the tool Img2Code I converted my image into a bitmap.

```
void Adafruit_GFX::drawXBitmap(int16_t x, int16_t y,
                               const uint8_t *bitmap, int16_t w, int16_t h,uint16_t color)
```

[image: screenshot]

How to include this code and print the bitmap on the tft?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: how to draw a xbm (bitmap) on my tft. I don't know how to include the big bitmap array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the function prototype you have show suggests, the data needs to be in a uint8_t array format.

```
void Adafruit_GFX::drawXBitmap(int16_t x, int16_t y,
            const uint8_t *bitmap, int16_t w, int16_t h,uint16_t color)
```

So your array data would look like:

```
const uint8_t myBitmap[] = { 0xff, 0xff, 0xc0, 0x00, 0xc0, 0xff,
    0xc0, 0xc0, 0xff, 0xff, 0xde, 0xad, 0xbe, 0xef,
    .... etc ....
    0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff
};
```

You then call the function with the needed parameters:

```
tft.drawXBitmap(10, 20, myBitmap, 100, 80, 0xFFFF);
```

That is assuming you want to place it at (top left corner) 10,20 and the bitmap is 100x80 pixels in size.  It will draw it in white (0xFFFF).